# htaccess - redirect if folder don't exist; follow htaccess on subfolder if it does

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a website running on Hostinger working fine. I am trying to run it on my PC with XAMPP but I can't get it to work.
htaccess files are not my expertise.

I have a root folder with a index.php file on the website.
An htaccess file on this folder redirects every file/folder that do not exist for the index.php file at root

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I also have a folder API with an index.php inside it. Inside this folder I have the exact same htaccess.
If I go to site.com/API/user on the server, it opens API/index.php file as intended.
But if I go to localhost/API/user on my computer, it opens index.php from the root directory not the API folder.

The following line does not exist on Hostinger, I had to add it on my PC otherwise it would open file test.php even when going to localhost/test which was breaking my code.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Does anyone knows what may be happening? I've been searching for hours, don't know what else to look for.

Comment: Take a look at your code: `RewriteBase /` . Now what do you think that the _relative_ path `index.php` will result in  considering that base? I'd say that `RewriteBase` is not what you want inside the `API` folder.

Comment: Well... That was easy, it worked. I just don't know why on the server and my computer it has different behaviors, but removing the RewriteBase from the folder API it worked.

Comment: "I just don't know why on the server and my computer it has different behaviors" - From the information you posted in the question, that doesn't make sense. So, either you were seeing a cached response, or there was in fact some difference in folder structure or `.htaccess` file content. Regarding `MultiViews` - there would be a directive in the server config that enabled it. This is arguably erroneous (although some shared hosts do enable it out of the box) - most of the time this should be disabled (it is disabled by _default_).